# ionic 2 how to load dynamically with index

Tags: angular, ionic2

For ionic 1 i have done like `ng-if="$index % 3 === 0"` But i need to load the data dynamically in grid view with two col in one row. How can i do that. i tried below code :

in my **schudle.ts :**

```
ResourceData = [{ name: "ksjs" },{ name: "daa" },{ name: "das" }, {name: "das" }, {name: "Computer Science" }, { name: "Moc" }]
```

My **html :**

```
 <div class="item item-body no-padding" style="border-width: 0px !important; overflow-y:hidden;height: 65%;">

                <div class="row no-padding" style="height: 65%;" *ngFor="let data of ResourceData" *ngIf="index % 2 == 0">
                    <div class="col col-50 custom-design2" style="background: url(url) no-repeat center;background-size: cover;">
                        <div class="custom-design1"><span class="grid-title">{{data[index].name}}</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-50 custom-design2" style="background: url(url) no-repeat center;background-size: cover;">
                        <div class="custom-design1"><span class="grid-title">{{data[index + 1].name}}</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div
```

But it din work . May be that `ngif` may be wrong. please tell me how can i solve this.

i need like this :

```
as      fa

fas     faaf

faf      faf

fafa     fafaf
```

So two col per row. Please tell me what i am doing wrong !!

Thanks

**ionic 1**

```
 <div class="row no-padding" ng-repeat="mydash in Data"  ng-if="$index % 3 === 0">
                <div class="col col-30 custom-design2" style="background: url({{Data[$index].Image}}) no-repeat center;background-size: cover;" ng-click="changestate(Data[$index])" ng-if="$index < Data.length">
                    <div class="custom-design1"><span class="grid-title">{{Data[$index].name}}</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-30 custom-design2" style="background: url({{Data[$index + 1].Image}}) no-repeat center;background-size: cover; " ng-click="changestate(Data[$index + 1])" ng-if="$index + 1 < Data.length">
                    <div class="custom-design1"><span class="grid-title">{{Data[$index + 1].name}}</span></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col col-30 custom-design2" style="background: url({{Data[$index + 2].Image}}) no-repeat center;background-size: cover; " ng-click="changestate(Data[$index + 2])" ng-if="$index + 2 < Data.length">
                    <div class="custom-design1"><span class="grid-title">{{Data[$index + 2].name}}</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using two [structural directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#one-per-element) in the same tag.Both `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` in one `div`.

> There's an easy solution for this use case: put the *ngIf on a container element that wraps the *ngFor element. One or both elements can be an ng-container so you don't have to introduce extra levels of HTML.

Use [ng-container](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#ngcontainer)

You can also get index by appending `let i =index` in `*ngFor`.

```
<div class="row no-padding" style="height: 65%;" *ngFor="let data of ResourceData;let i = index">
     <ng-container *ngIf=" i % 2 == 0">
          <div class="col col-50 custom-design2" style="background: url(url) no-repeat center;background-size: cover;">
               <div class="custom-design1"><span class="grid-title">{{ResourceData[i].name}}</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-50 custom-design2" style="background: url(url) no-repeat center;background-size: cover;">
                 <div class="custom-design1"><span class="grid-title">{{ResourceData[i+1].name}}</span></div>
             </div>
     </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried, but no data are showing in my grid view. Its empty. And no console messages too

Comment: what is index ?

Comment: bro thats what i applied in ionic 1. to get the first index of hard code value in my controller. to populate it ib grid view dynamically

Comment: so i tried like same using index. But it din work. i thought getting index of hard code value may be wrong.

Comment: the first index of the _for loop_ or is it a variable in component? I have no idea of `ionic 1`.. so I wont get the comparison

Comment: please check my post. i have some array of object called `ResourceData` . So inside `ResourceData` in have `name` know. So i need to display that in my grid view with 2 col per row. as per my html code in my post

Comment: okay leave about ionic 1. Now how can i dynamically load my `name` in my grid view with 2 col per row

Comment: any solution please

Comment: is index the index of ResourceData..you are checking for odd even to put in each div?

Comment: yes so, if i have 7 data in my `ResourceData`. Then in my div the grid will have two col in one row. so first index of `ResourceData` have to start from first grid and it have to display full `name`

Comment: check my updated answer..is that what you were looking for>

Comment: bro only two grid is working. measn that i have 6 data in `ResourceData`. But its showimg first two only. Dynamically its not showing all 6 data like 6 grid

Comment: i have posted how i got top work in ionic 1. can you please se that and help me out

Comment: i tried adding the length of `ResourceData` to show. But its not working by that method also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143194/discussion-between-suraj-and-sinha).

Comment: Nice, but this work only for 2 columns... I'm searching for a dynamic solution, any idea?