# create new row after every two column using angular2 in ionic2 App

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-template, ngfor

I wish to achieve a structure where we can use ngFor and create new row after every 2 columns.

The array looks like this

```
public displayArray=[{
    "categoryName":"Bags",
    "categoryProducts":[
    {
    "name":"product1",
    "price":"34"
    },
    {
    "name":"product2",
    "price":"34"
    },
    {
    "name":"product3",
    "price":"34"
    },
    {
    "name":"product4",
    "price":"34"
    }]
}];
```

I have to iterate over the categoryProducts Array and create a grid of 2 rows and each row having 2 columns

Below is what i have tried.I know this is wrong so please guide me how to achieve this using angular 2

```
<!---------------------------------------------->
<div style="background: #424242;"  *ngFor="let item of displayArray; let i = index">
<ion-row padding-horizontal>
    <ion-col>
     <ion-label style="color:white;">{{item.categoryName}}</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col style="text-align: end;">
      <button ion-button small  style="text-transform: none;">More</button>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>

<ion-card>

  <div *ngFor="let p of item.categoryProducts;let j=index">

  <ion-grid>


  <ion-row>

    <ion-col col-50 >
      <div style="text-align: center;height:150px;">
        <img src="assets/img/jpeg.jpg" style="width : 100% ; height : 100%">

      </div>
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <h4>{{p.name}}</h4>
        <h4>Rs {{p.price}}</h4>
      </div>
    </ion-col >



  </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

  </div>
```

This is drawing one column per row and creating 4 rows for each of the object.

One way is to change the displayArray and make it such that it suits the UI. But cant we do it without modifying the array?

Thanks
Shruti Nair

Comment: you mean something like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43735925/4826457

Comment: Thanks! got it working