# ionic 3 grid view with two col per row

Tags: html, gridview, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic3

I have one screen , which will have the data to display from database. I already tried grid view in ionic 1 its fine. But ionic 3 i don't know how to do the grid view.From database i will get like 10 or 11 or 13 category names , that names i need to display in grid view with background some image.

I know how to display background image.But i need to display 2 col per row.here my code that i will use to fetch data from database.....

```
  another(loading:any) {

        this.subcatdata = { CatID: this.categoryid };

        this.authService.subcatte(this.subcatdata).then((result) => {

            this.data = result;

            console.log(this.data);

            if (this.data.status == 1) {
                this.Catdata = this.data.SubCatgeoryList;


                for (let i = 0; i < this.Catdata.length; i++) {
                    console.log(this.Catdata[i].SubCategoryName);
                }
            }

            else if (this.data.status == 0) {

                let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: 'Error',
                    subTitle: 'Please Enter Valid Username & Password',
                    buttons: ['OK']
                });
                alert.present();
            }
            loading.dismiss();            

        }, (err) => {
            loading.dismiss();
        });
    }
```

In my above code i will get the subcatgory name by using below code :

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.Catdata.length; i++) {
                        console.log(this.Catdata[i].SubCategoryName);
                    }
```

In **my html :**

```
<div class="item item-body no-padding" style="border-width: 0px !important;">  

  <div class="row no-padding" *ngFor="let data of Catdata; let i = index" (click)="openresources(Catdata[i].SubCatID)">

          <div class="col col-50 custom-design2" style="background: url(background url) no-repeat center;background-size: cover;">
               <div class="custom-design1"><span class="grid-title">{{Catdata[i].SubCategoryName}}</span></div>
            </div>
</div> 


</div>
```

My `scss` :

```
.gallery {
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
  div.no-padding, ion-item.no-padding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
div.custom-design2 {
  height: 153px;
    padding: 1px;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #FFF !important;
}
.no-scroll .scroll-content{
     overflow: hidden;
}

div.custom-design1 {
  text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    height: 153px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}

div.custom-design1.extended {
    height: 153px;
}

span.grid-title {
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.transparent {
    background: transparent !important;
}

.full_height {
    height: 100% !important;
    border: none;
}
```

Now in my screen its coming like one data per row, with full row background.

But what i need is two col ( 2 data/sub cat name per row).I know we need to use index + 1, but in ionic 3 i dont know how to do.

If any help, that will be helpfull

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43735925/4826457

Comment: @suraj   i have tried but its woking for one time.After that its not shwoing any data in screen...some times work,,,some time not working

Comment: there could be other bugs..

Comment: @suraj   in my console , i am not getting any error...But its works first time..Then its not working

Comment: can you create a sample plunker?

Comment: due u have skype... i dont know how can i do that plunker

Comment: cant access skype where I work bro.. create a plunker if you can